# cshtml post with asp-route parameter

Tags: c#, razor

Why am I getting a null for my `py` parameter? There's other examples in the code already that use hard links and `py` populates, its just in the `form` post that `py` is null.  `tn` is OK.

Probably a simple fix, but not sure where the problem is.

```
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Fields" asp-route-py="9" asp-route-tn="1" method="post">

// GET: Fields/Edit/5
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long? id, int? py, int? tn)
```

Comment: Why you have added static value in `asp-route-py`? Usually the value of route is added dynamically `asp-route-py="@item.ID"`

Comment: @Llazar just testing that is why its hardcoded

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your controller and there's not enough code to understand the problem.

Comment: I am using breakpoints in the controller that how I know its null.  Assuming what you mean is a breakpoint under that Edit method in my question.  its just the `py` parameter that is null.  Is there another class that validates this flow?

Comment: Assuming you have other code in edit method right?

Comment: does tn get the value of tn? so it = 1 right? and id's value?

Comment: @Llazar Oh most definitely but wouldn't that code be irrelevant to my question?  The code there is fine as it gets called by other actions, it just seems that `py` is ignored in the `form post`

Comment: @topher Correct.  `id` is OK as well.

Comment: If the form is post why edit method is Get?

Comment: @Llazar Not sure if that comment is wrong.  I've inherited this project from a different team and its full of bugs.  Lucky me (=  I know that method is called when the form submit button is clicked.  Maybe I missed a method prior to that... hmm

Comment: @Llazar You solved my issue.  There was another POST edit a few hundred lines down.-----------------

 `[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long id, int? py, int? tn, [Bind("Id,`

Comment: @Llazar If you make an answer, I'll mark that as correct.  Thank you!

Comment: @kenyu73 I thought something was not right but without seeing all the code can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your project must have another edit method but this method must be Post like the form you have posted.

Usually a crud application has 2 methods one Post to post data to the server and one Get to retrieve data from the server.

Edit method with Get request

```
/ GET: Fields/Edit/5
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long? id, int? py, int? tn)
```

Edit method with Post request

```
[HttpPost] 
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long id, int? py, int? tn, [Bind("Id,....)
```